# Angular 2 new (RC1) router. CanReuse interface

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

With old router (now `@angular/router-deprecated`) I could implement `CanReuse` interface to tell angular not to recreate the component on route change. (Of course if the route still leads to the same component).
In new `Router` class there is no such interface. How I can achieve the same effect now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question earlier and received word that it will be in a future update [Angular 2 new router routerCanReuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353503/angular-2-new-rc1-routercanreuse#comment62222875_37353503)

Comment: OK. Thank you. Didnt find it by interface name instead on method name.